# If $f$ has compact support, choose $x_j \to 0$ so that the functions $f(x - x_j)$ are independent

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure

Let $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function. Let $A$ denote the support of $f$, and suppose that $A$ is compact and that $m(A) > 0$, where $m$ denotes Lebesgue measure.

> I would like to should that there exists a sequence $\{x_j\}_{j=1}^\infty \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ with $x_j \to 0$ such that the functions $f_j = f(x - x_j)$ are linearly independent outside a set of measure zero.

This construction is made in the proof of the Theorem 7.12 in Teschl's *Mathematical Methods in Quantum Mechanics*, and is part of an alternate strategy (avoiding complex analysis) to show that if a function $f$ and its Fourier transform $\hat{f}$ are both compactly supported, then $f \equiv 0$.

The support of the function $f_j$ is $A + x_j$, but I need to find a suitable way of choosing the $x_j$ so that the sets $A_j = A + x_j$ are sufficiently separated to ensure the linear independence.

Hints or solutions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: What does it mean to be linearly independent outside a set of measure zero?

Comment: Just convergence $x_j\to 0$ is certainly not enough because you could have $x_j=x_k$ for some $j\neq k$. Perhaps you are satisfied with the assumption that $\|x_j\|$ *strictly* decreases to $0$? Then you should try to see that the support of $f_j$ cannot be covered by the supports of $f_k$ with $k>j$.

Comment: @Jose27-I take it to mean that there exists a Lebesgue measurable set $E$ with $m(E) = 0$ so that on $ \mathbb{R}^n \setminus E$, for each finite subcollection $f_{n_1}, \dots, f_{n_M}$, the function $\sum_{j = 1}^M c_j f_{n_j}$ does not vanish identically unless each $c_j = 0$.

Comment: @Jochen-Yes, I agree this is what I want to show (and also that the part of $f_j$'s support which is not covered has positive Lebesgue measure). I'm still trying to find right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the question, you can choose $x_j=a_j e$ with $e$ any non zero vector and $a_j\searrow 0$, and you can remove "outside a set of measure zero".

Consider the affine hyperplane orthogonal to $e$ touching $A$ from outside, that is $H_t=\{x:\langle x, e\rangle =t\}$ with $t=\sup_{y\in A} \langle y,e\rangle$, and pick any point $x_A$ in the intersection $H_t\cap A$. Then for any given finite set $\{a_{i_1},\ldots, a_{i_k}\}$ the function among $f_{j}$ with biggest $a_j$ is the only one not vanishing near its "touching point" $x_A+x_{j}$. This forces its coefficient in the linear combination to be zero, and you can proceed inductively.